# Regex with last occurence, lookahead and a not-only condition

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need a regex which searches for the last underscore in a string and matches if:

- There is no underscore at all
- The last underscore is followed by "0.abc"
- The last underscore is followed by "*.abc", where * can't consist only of digits and has to be a non-empty string
- In all cases it has to end with ".abc"

Valid cases:

```
dsafjukfa.abc
dfgdsafdsf_0.abc
eatAda-gfda_fdagfda_asf01.abc
eatgdagfda_fdagfda_asf01_0.abc
eatgdagfda_fdagfda_asf01_1a.abc
```

Invalid cases:

```
asdfsadf_546.abc
eatgdagfda_fdagfda_asf01_1.abc
dsafjukfa.xyz
dfgdsafdsf_0.xyz
eatAda-gfda_fdagfda_asf01.xyz
eatgdagfda_fdagfda_asf01_0.xyz
eatgdagfda_fdagfda_asf01_1a.xyz
```

I basically need a combination of last occurrence, positive/negative lookahead and a non-only digit string

Everything should run in Pythons regex engine.

EDIT: Since requested: Some attempts doing it partly have been looking like

```
"^[^_]*$"
"(?!.*_)(0|\w*).abc"
```

But since this doesn't help much I just described which techniques I expect to be required.

Comment: What is the regex you've attempted?

Comment: This is "Write this code for me..." and not on topic here. You should at least show some effort to do this yourself.

Comment: @MatthewG., did you take a look at my solution?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm still figuring out why it works perfectly in pythex, but it fails on for example "asd_0.abc" in my ipython environment. Might the reason be that I'm still using Python 2.7? The line `re.match("^[^_]*$|_(?=0\.abc[^_]*$)|_(?=\d*[^\d_][^_]*\.abc[^_]*$)", "asd_0.abc")` leaves an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[^_]*.abc$|_(?=0\.abc[^_]*$)|_(?=\d*[^\d_][^_]*\.abc[^_]*$)
```

1. There is no underscore at all - `^[^_]*$`
2. Underscore, followed by *0.abc* - `_(?=0\.abc)`
3. Underscore, followed by **.abc*, where *** is a variable amount of characters, at least one of which is a digit - `_(?=\d*\D.*\.abc)`
4. We make the said underscore the last one by ensuring that there is no underscore after it til the end of the string.

[See it in action](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5B%5E_%5D*%24%7C_(%3F%3D0%5C.abc%5B%5E_%5D*%24)%7C_(%3F%3D%5Cd*%5B%5E%5Cd_%5D%5B%5E_%5D*%5C.abc%5B%5E_%5D*%24)&test_string=dsafjukfa.abc%0Adfgdsafdsf_0.abc%0AeatAda-gfda_fdagfda_asf01.abc%0Aeatgdagfda_fdagfda_asf01_0.abc%0Aeatgdagfda_fdagfda_asf01_1a.abc%0A%0Aasdfsadf_546.abc%0Aeatgdagfda_fdagfda_asf01_1.abc&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

---

A more readable alternative to implement the last rule is to use a separate lookahead:

```
^[^_]*.abc$|(?:_(?=0\.abc)|_(?=\d*\D.*\.abc))(?=[^_]*$)
```

[See it in action](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5B%5E_%5D*%24%7C(%3F%3A_(%3F%3D0%5C.abc)%7C_(%3F%3D%5Cd*%5CD.*%5C.abc))(%3F%3D%5B%5E_%5D*%24)&test_string=dsafjukfa.abc%0Adfgdsafdsf_0.abc%0AeatAda-gfda_fdagfda_asf01.abc%0Aeatgdagfda_fdagfda_asf01_0.abc%0Aeatgdagfda_fdagfda_asf01_1a.abc%0A%0Aasdfsadf_546.abc%0Aeatgdagfda_fdagfda_asf01_1.abc&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: As written above both expressions don't match a single string containing at least one underscore - even though these strings work perfectly in pythex. Is there a difference in the Python 2 and Python 3 regex interpreters? I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: @MatthewG., don't think so. You can see it working [here](https://repl.it/BBZG) on *Python 2.7.2*. The only thing that comes to mind is - are you using `match` or `search`? Because `match` has implicit `^`.

Comment: Oh, you're totally right. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I missed to add an example that the string has to end with ".abc" and not ".abd" or anything else. This doesn'T work with the expression by now. So the correct solution would be `^[^_]*.abc$|_(?=0\.abc[^_]*$)|_(?=\d*[^\d_][^_]*\.abc[^_]*$)`

Comment: @MatthewG., if you meant that a string should end with an *underscore*, followed by *yadi yadi yada* then the problem is way easier than "the last *underscore* should be followed by *yadi yadi yada*". Therefore, the regex can be simplified a lot. But this would also be sad because another user had posted such solution and I added a comment that it doesn't work for the `_.abc` case when in fact it was the expected behavior, but wasn't included in the original question. They ended up deleting they answer. :(

Comment: The above regex is still wrong and I can't re-edit by now, so: `^[^_]*.abc$|(?:_(?=0\.abc$)|_(?=\d*\D.*\.abc$))(?=[^_]*$)` would be correct

Comment: No, the only thing I didn't mention clearly enough is that it should match `asd_0.abc`, but not `asd_0.abd`

Comment: @MatthewG., but it doesn't match `asd_0.abd` the way it is now. [Try it](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5B%5E_%5D*%24%7C(%3F%3A_(%3F%3D0%5C.abc)%7C_(%3F%3D%5Cd*%5CD.*%5C.abc))(%3F%3D%5B%5E_%5D*%24)&test_string=asd_0.abd&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: That's what was intended. It should only match if the string ends with .abc - I'll add some cases to the original problem description